# Every time I open Photoshop CS3, it says it needs to repair itself

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, adobe-photoshop

It happens every time I open, and I do click Repair. I repaired disk permissions on my drive to no avail. The problem started after using Apple's magical migration tool to move from my Powerbook G4 (running 10.5)

Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard on an Intel iMac.

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled CS3? Be aware that officially CS3 and 10.6 are not compatible, although many people are using the combination without problems. Do you know the exact wording of what the error is that it wants to repair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend reinstalling it because, the migration tool moves some files into locations that could create problems with permissions, which maybe the case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is that Snow Leopard moved around Photoshop to an area in which Photoshop cannot find itself. I once moved Photoshop on 10.5 and it prompted me to do that. My repair had no problems but since you are on a completely different OS you may have to reinstall.